# Why is $ \lvert x-y\rvert \lvert x+y\rvert \leq 2 \lvert x-y \rvert$

Tags: inequality

Why is $ \lvert x-y\rvert \lvert x+y\rvert \leq 2 \lvert x-y \rvert$ for $x,y \in [0,1] $ ?

Answer (score 3):

This is because
$$ |x+y|\le|x|+|y|\le 2. $$

Answer (score 1):

I have sketched a graphical "proof":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because $x,y\in[0,1]\implies |x+y|-2\leq 0$ and so $|x-y|(|x+y|-2)\leq 0$.